# Terdata using pound sign for the name of the fields

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a task to translate some Teradata scripts to BigQuery SQL. However, I can't find what the syntax with pound sign in the name of the alias means.

```
SELECT
     A  AS SOME_COLUMM_1
    ,B AS SOME_COLUMN_2
    ,C     AS SOME_COLUMN_3# /* <------- HERE */
    ,COUNT(*)      AS E FROM
     SOME_DB.SOME_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no meaning, '#', '$' and '_' are simply allowed characters in an object name besides 'a'-'z' and '0'-'9'.

If BigQuery doesn't support `SOME_COLUMN_3#` as object name, you can either change it or double quote it: `"SOME_COLUMN_3#"`

Double quoted names can include almost any character and allow using of reserved keywords as names like a table named `"table"`.

Caution: In Standard SQL double quoted names are case sensitive, but not in Teradata, e.g. "a" and "A" are different names in Standard SQL, but the same in Teradata.